# NodeJS : How to serve securely without exposing certificat content

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

Is there a way to deliver secure content (https:443) with node without exposing certificate contents ?

```
import express from 'express'
import fs from 'fs'
import https from 'https'

const app:express.Express = express()

const options: https.ServerOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/my.private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/my.public.crt')
}

const httpsServer:https.Server = https.createServer(options, app)
[ code here ]
httpsServer.listen(443);
```

This works, but my web app has to run as root user, which I think is a bad idea. Also, my certificate contents, especially my private key, is unveiled in a web context.

Is there a way to pipe encryption & decryption process outside current node execution context ? Like php/apache pattern : Apache handles the ecrypt/decrypt process and executes php scripts as *www-data* user. Php script can't read certificate content, which means they are 100 % safe and not reachable from php context.

I know we can set up an apache layer to proxy secure content (https) to unsecure content (http) locally so node could handle it. But this adds a considerable layer of complexity. Anyone has a safer approach using node only ? Like using a « third party app » that would essentially encode / decode content using provided certificate paths, running as *ssl-cert* user ?

Comment: Did you ever find the best practice for this?  I'm in the same situation -- got the prototype working, but now the certs and passwords are just sitting around in the open/file system.  And that can't be right...

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how this can secure a private key, but let's say.

You can also use Nginx over Express to "secure" the private key.

Generally, all ports up to 1000 are accessible only by root user and you physically can't run something there without root rights.

Comment: Let's say I give away ssh access to my server as « www-data » user  : anyone can't compromise anything. Apache runs under this precious « sheltered context » (and can listen to 80 and 443 ports). That's why I state that my private key is 100 % secure under apache whatever if things goes wrong. If I provide root ssh access, what I must do to make the provided exemple working, that makes my hole server compromised :/

Comment: @Simmoniz 1. Do not login via ssh as root, 2. Use the flexible sudo utility. 3. ??? 4. PROFIT!